# If each of 'n' integers is chosen at random from the set {$1,2,...,f$}, then find the probability that there sum is '$s$'.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If each of **'n'** integers is chosen at random from the set **{$1,2,...,f$}**, then find the probability that there sum is **'$s$'**, ( $n$ $\leq$ $s$ $\leq$ $nf$ )

> Here, there is another particular case of this problem, If **'n'** unbiased dice are cast, we have to show the probability that the sum is **'$s$'** will be,
> $6^{-n}$ $\sum_{i=0}^{s-n/6}(-1)^i\binom ni\binom{s-6i-1}{n-1}$, i.e I think here the set is {$1,2,3,4,5,6$} to choose the values of **$n$** .

Comment: Clarification requested: is sampling done with or without replacement?  Here, the question is relevant because if **no replacement**, then the minimum value obtainable is obviously $\left[\sum_{k=1}^n k\right] = n(n+1)/2.$

Comment: Please award the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim seems trivial to me.

We have $n$ integers $x1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, each of them is in the set $\{1,2,\dots,f\}$, so
$$ 1 ≤ x_i ≤ f \qquad \forall \, i = 1, \dots, n .$$

Then we can easily bound the sum s:
$$ s = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i ≥ \sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n$$
and
$$ s = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^n f = nf .$$

This means
$$ n ≤ s ≤ nf .$$

Notice that I didn't use any info about the randomness here, it is a general result which holds regardless of *how* the integers are chosen.

Comment: as I'm reading the question, what is asked for is the *probability that the sum is $s$*, given some $s$ satisfying $n\leq s\leq nf$. (i.e. $n\leq s\leq nf$ is a precondition on $s$, and not the claim)

Comment: Oh, that would have more sense, indeed! You are right, but the question was poorly written